# sas time format dates

Tags: time, sas, format, series

I want to analyze a time series data in SAS. I have a data set in excel that I'm importing into SAS University Edition, which is very easy to do. The time variable is 5-minute increments from 6:00 to 8:55 for each day of the week.

When I ran timeseries, I get the error: “ERROR: The data set WORK.DATA is not sorted by the ID variable. At observation number 37, time=6:00:00, but time=8:55:00 for the previous observation.”.

My understanding is that the TIME variable is not unique to each observation. My question is how to make the time variable unique for all cases.

The link to the data is below if someone wants to play with it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18SY7stsXS0CztWda2KavZXCwaMQA5yzG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sounds like the error message is saying that 6AM is before 8:55AM. Which makes sense.  What do you want to do about it?  Does that represent the start of a new day? a new subject?

Comment: Have you sorted the data by the ID variable and time value yet?

Comment: I got `website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. ` Please consider pasting code and a sample of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert you time to datetime  so that each row is unique, hence the datetime will be your ID and sort by ID.

In your data, your date is just the day of the week (ex. Mon).  You can either:

- Add the Date, then concatenate date and time to get the datetime; you can use the sas [DHMS()](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000179419.htm) function for this,
- Add the Datetime directly in your data.

Comment: Thank you all for the swift responses. I ended up getting the dates for the days (m-f) in the yymmdd format and then concatenated it. i then applied the datetime format, sorted and ran the time series. Thank you all.

Comment: You are welcome. Please up Vote or accept my answer if it helped.